# Track email sent from salesforce

Tags: email

Is it possible to track whether the email has been sent or not?

If not what is the cause for failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a feature to track the emails that is sent from salesforce.

Please refer to the following links:
https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?err=1&id=email_logs.htm&siteLang=en_US

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=email_logs_format.htm&language=en_US

Path to access Email Logs : Monitor | Logs | Email Logs

Comment: Great, but if I require it in visual force page which would be available for me every time without requiring me to send a request. Is it possible: D

Comment: I don't think thats possible, it requires Salesforce request to get the logs. Can raise a case with Salesforce regarding this.